# Django: Timezone stored in MySQL DB is not correct

Tags: mysql, django, timezone

I have an application which is using 'Asia/Taipei' as its timezone in settings.py and using  the auto_now=true on one of the datetimefield on models.py:

```
--- settings.py ---
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Taipei'
--- models.py ---
models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

On my system, Taipei is also used as my timezone:
[image]

On the MySQL Workbench, I already queried for both global and session tz and their returns are "SYSTEM":
[image]

My question is when an entry is added to DB, the timezone specified on the system and on settings.py was not used. See sample snapshot:
[image]

What am I lacking? Doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

Typically, database will store the UTC time by default and the corresponding application will do the conversion based on the settings/configurations.

In your case, it depends on your `USE_TZ` setting.

> When USE_TZ is False, this is the time zone in which Django will store
>   all datetimes. When USE_TZ is True, this is the default time zone that
>   Django will use to display datetimes in templates and to interpret
>   datetimes entered in forms.

For more details, you can refer

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_TZ
- http://garmoncheg.blogspot.in/2012/03/new-in-django-14-timezones.html

Answer (score 4):

it's working now. I just set **USE_TZ = False**